# "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" react and node.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs

https://github.com/dongha1992/MERN-boilerplate

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hTKR.jpg)

hello. currently I tried to practice shopping mall clone as react and node.js

I faced that problem I attached. it doesn't seem that error for  cos I copied same as tutorial but it is something wrong with node.js(localhost:5000)

I tried to everything to fix it but don't know how to approach. please help me!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOh5q.jpg)

Comment: have you console your props ?

Comment: what is `props` and what is `props.images` can you show a console.log please

Comment: What does this log statement (https://github.com/dongha1992/MERN-boilerplate/blob/e100039d82864cb4046d032140d4e0e29f1a9c47/client/src/components/views/LandingPage/LandingPage.js#L13) output?

Comment: @VyasArpit  for image is empty string..

Comment: @Red Baron  I will upload new one thanks man!

Comment: @prekolna what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Probably an asynchronous request that populates your props.images hasn't returned a response.
Prefix props.images && to props.images.map function
That way only when the prop is present does the the map occur. Like this
{props.images && props.image.map(image=>.........

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is often an issue of a `variable` taking on different `value` during code execution. To safeguard again this, it's recommended to make sure that the `props` or a specific variable is defined before it's used.

```js
// alternative-1

function ImageSlider(props){
  return props.images && (
    <div>
      <Carousel autoplay>
        {props.images.map((image, index) => 
          // ...
        )}
      // ...
    </div>
  );
};
```

OR

```js
// alternative-2

function ImageSlider(props){
  return props.images ? (
    <div>
      <Carousel autoplay>
        {props.images.map((image, index) => 
          // ...
        )}
      // ...
    </div>
  ) : null;
};
```

Critically, here's what is happening in the `return()` statement.

1. **Alternative-1 (Implicit):**

- The second part, `<div>` is only rendered if the first part is `true`.
- In core JavaScript, `undefined` is equivalent to `false` so `props.images` is `true` only when `images` is `!undefined` (not undefined; in other words, images is defined).

2. **Alternative-2 (Explicit):**

- This one is more direct, as long as `props.image` is `undefined`, we return `null`.
  (Remember, a valid react component must return something. If nothing, then return `null`)
- Only when `props.images` is defined, then we return the `<div>`.

These added checks ensure that your code never breaks, in this case your `map()` will always be called on a defined variable (props.images).

[Here's a good read on Conditional rendering from the react team](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html).

Comment: it works but it still doesn't work for showing image as LandingPage. don't know what to do

Comment: Kindly explain what you mean by "it doesn't work for showing image as LandingPage". I didn't understand that part. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to call the map function on data that hasn't been received from your axios request. You should add some logic so that any components that rely on your request data render only if it exits, easily done with a ternary operator.

It looks like many components (including imageSlider) depend on data you try to access when you call your renderCards function on line 54 of your App.